# Higher partial derivatives of a regular function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, regular-rings

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety over a field $k$, and let $x\in X$. Let $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a regular system of parameters at $x$, so that $\Omega^1_{X/k}$ is locally free at $x$ with basis $dx_1,\dots,dx_n$.

Whenever $f$ is a regular function defined on a (Zariski-)neighbourhood of $x$, one may define the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)\in\kappa(x)$ of $f$ at $x$ as being the unique scalars of $\kappa(x)$ verifying $df(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x)dx_1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(x)dx_n$ (where $df(x)$ is the image of $df$ in $(\Omega^1_{X/k})_x\otimes_{\mathscr{O}_{X,x}}\kappa(x)$).

Now, I would like to define higher partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to the $x_i$'s. How may this be done?

Comment: You might want to look up "bundles (or sheaves) of principle parts." These are sheaves associated with a given (let's say line bundle for simplicity) which parametrize Taylor expansions (to a given order) of sections of that line bundle at each point. The only reference I know off hand is Eisenbud and Harris *3264 and All That*, specifically the chapter on Singular Elements of Linear Series.

Comment: @TabesBridges: thanks, this is exactly what I needed. For further reference, one may note that "Principal part bundles" are also called "Jet bundles".

Comment: Great, glad it was the right thing. Two other points of terminology: While the term that I mentioned is AFAIK exclusive to algebraic geometry, "jet bundle" is also used in differential geometry to describe what I believe is essentially the same construction, but presumably the details can get much more complicated. Also, I don't know the motivation for the term "bundle of principle parts," which I believe is due to Grothendieck, but it does NOT refer to the principal parts that one encounters in complex analysis.

Comment: @TabesBridges: The remark at the end of section 9.2 in *3264 and All That* suggests that the terminology has been chosen by Grothendieck and Dieudonné, and comes from the notion of "principal part" of a meromorphic function at a point (the negative part of the laurent series of the meromorphic function at that point).

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten about that remark, although they do note that it is actually a conflicting usage.